# How do I give parallel write access to a file without collisions?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, file-locking

I have some child processes which should write some logs into a common file. I am wondering if this code work so that the processes will write into the common file without collisions:

```
sub appendLogs {
    open FILE, "+>>", $DMP or die "$!";
    flock FILE, LOCK_EX or die "$!";
    print FILE "xyz\n";
    close FILE;
}
```

If not, could you give me any hints, how I could fix or improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as every process that tries to write to file uses `flock`, they will go without collisions.

Comment: But what if I need to write to file without an option to die if I cannot obtain successful `flock`? Your solution is not good enough for critical apps.

Comment: @Ωmega you don't write to a single point of failure in "critical apps". And this question is about logs.

Answer (score 4):

For logging purpose, I would use [Log4perl](http://p3rl.org/Log::Log4perl) instead of reinventing the wheel. It has a support for what you are looking.

- [How can I synchronize access to an appender?](http://p3rl.org/Log::Log4perl::FAQ#How-can-I-synchronize-access-to-an-appender-)
- [Log4Perl bundling logging from several programs into one log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180752/log4perl-bundling-logging-from-several-programs-into-one-log)

Comment: thank you very much for feedback!! well.. altough i have written, i need an algorithm for logging, i... don't really mean a logging... i must save some part of xml file...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like your code to be portable, you should seek to the end of the file after you lock the filehandle but before you write to it. See the "mailbox appender" example in [`perldoc -f flock`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#flock), which is similar to what you are doing.

```
sub appendLogs {
    open FILE, "+>>", $DMP or die "$!";
    flock FILE, LOCK_EX or die "$!";
    seek FILE, 0, 2;       # <--- after lock, move cursor to end of file
    print FILE "xyz\n";
    close FILE;
}
```

The `seek` may be necessary because another process could append the file (and move the position of the end of the file) after you open the file handle but before you acquire the lock.

Comment: On linux (or POSIX in general?), the seek is unnecessary. "If the file was open(2)ed with O_APPEND, the file offset is first set to the end of the file before writing.  The adjustment of the file offset and the write operation are performed as an atomic step."

Comment: @ikegami - fair enough. I rewrote my first sentence.

Comment: What if dying after unsuccessful `flock` call is not an option?